# Newtonsoft.Json, Difference in file version and reference version

Tags: assembly-binding-redirect

I was trying to do a binding redirect for an older version of Newtonsoft.Json to the latest version and kept on failing. Eventually updated to a range from 0.0.0.0 - 9.0.0.0 -> 9.0.0.0 and it worked.

```
 <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="0000000" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-9.0.0.0" newVersion="9.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
```

But when I first initially started, I looked up the file version via file properties and added the version number **9.0.1.19813** and kept getting an error stating that the assembly could not be found. I could not find a reason why it could not find it until I looked up the version number via properties under references and the file version was **9.0.0.0**

Any reason why the file version in file properties and the version shown in reference properties would be different and causing reference issues?

Also, to confirm I used ildasm.exe and it shows **ver 9.0.0.0**. I am a bit confused.

[image]

any comments would be helpful.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Found an explanation at Microsoft docs.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-nz/help/556041

Comment: I found this helpful in better understanding assembly vs. file versions. I was running into an issue where I mistakenly was using this <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-9.0.1.0" newVersion="9.0.1.0" /> when I should have simply been referencing 9.0.0.0.

Comment: Please don't do link only answers. Always put the content in the answer and then only link to support that content.\